# Unable to decode сyrillic text with Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, text-decoding

I have the following text:

```
РђРЅРЅР° РњРµСЂРєСѓР»РѕРІР°
```

With help of the following online decoder https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en I was able to decode mentioned string to the correct one:

```
Анна Меркулова
```

[image]

Source encoding is UTF-8 and the target is WINDOWS-1251

but I still unable to do it programmatically in Java:

```
String utf8String = new String("РђРЅРЅР° РњРµСЂРєСѓР»РѕРІР°".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
String ansiString = new String(utf8String.getBytes("UTF-8"), "windows-1251");
System.out.println(ansiString);
```

returns

```
Р С’Р Р…Р Р…Р В° Р СљР ВµРЎР‚Р С”РЎС“Р В»Р С•Р Р†Р В°
```

What am I doing wrong and how to properly convert the string?

Comment: String in Java uses internally always the same encoding. new String() creates one String from the encoding you set. If you want to output another encoding you must open an outputstream where you set the encoding. You could use an OutputStreamWriter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to assign the `String`(s) a `Charset`, but what you really need to do is *extract* the `bytes` with a specific `Charset`

```
final byte[] bytes = "РђРЅРЅР° РњРµСЂРєСѓР»РѕРІР°".getBytes("UTF-8");
final String utf8String = new String(bytes);
final byte[] bytes1 = utf8String.getBytes("windows-1251");
final String ansiString = new String(bytes1);
```

And by the way, you don't need all of that

```
final byte[] bytes = "РђРЅРЅР° РњРµСЂРєСѓР»РѕРІР°".getBytes("windows-1251");
final String result = new String(bytes);
```